# How do I put an emblem on my car/clothes in GTA Online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I designed an emblem on the Rockstar Social Club website and published it.  It's been a few days (as I know it can take several days to process), but it's not obvious to me how to find this emblem in game.  When I go to the clothing store/mod shop my crew emblem just looks like a yellow checkerboard.

How I do to get the emblem I published on my gear?

Comment: I have this exact same problem!  I thought I just formatted my emblem wrong, but I will check again if it still looks like a yellow checkerboard

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure that you have selected the right logo via Rockstar's social club in your crew management page.

Sometimes, you'll have to wait 24 to 72 hours to see the update but it should be faster by now since most bugs are fixed.

After that have a look in T-Shirt section in a clothe store and select the Crew Emblem. If nothing appears, there's a problem on Rockstar's servers and should be resolve soon. As for me, I have no problem to update my emblem, it get updated in the next hour.

Good luck